# Convert String to ListViewItem object name

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to convert String to ListViewItem variable. For example:

```
string string1 = "myItem";
```

but I couldn't convert it to ListViewItem, such as `ListViewItem "myItem" = new ListViewItem();`

Answer (score 0):

There is  the difference between an object and a variable. Objects themselves don't have names. Variable names are decided at compile-time. You can't access variables via an execution-time-determined name except via reflection.

But you can wrap it in an object that contains name

```
public class ListViewItemName:ListViewItem
{
    
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public ListViewItemName(string itemName, string name)
    {
        ItemName=itemName;
        base.Name=  name;
    }
}
```

You can use it this way:

```
var string1 = "myItem";
var listViewItemName = new ListViewItemName (string1,"item1");
```

But for practical use array maybe better:

```
var items = new ListViewItemName[] { listViewItemName1,listViewItemName2 ... };
```

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't support dynamic *variable* names.

Depending on your requirements, you may want to use a `Dictionary<string, ListViewItem>`:

```
Dictionary<string, ListViewItem> listViews = new Dictionary<string, ListViewItem>();
//add:
listViews[string1] = new ListViewItem();
//get:
ListViewItem lvi = listViews[string1];
```

Or just use compile-time variables as usual.